# return with inner loop in a function which returns value

Tags: c++

I have a doubt as how return works in this case in C++. What happens to loops once condition matches and we need to return value.

```
some function(){
    for( )//outer loop with i and other values
    {
        for( )// inner loop with i and other values {
            some condition using if which on match return a value val (call it x here)
            return x;
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

Comment: The `return` statement returns from the function

Comment: Once the condition matches, the function returns `x` and the rest of the code is not executed.

Comment: `return` Terminates the execution of a function and returns control to the calling function.

Comment: `return` returns, always.

Comment: Four answers in the comments section already. FML.

Comment: @GauravSehgal: destructor of automatic variables are called.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "how does return work?" "it returns"  is hardly a great Q/A

Comment: @M.M. No, it's not, but that does not mean the A should be posted in the wrong place instead.

Comment: i was hoping that the comments would prompt OP to clarify his misunderstanding

Comment: Looks clear enough to me.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing "happens" to the loops. Just like it always does, `return` returns from the function.

The loops evaporate into oblivion, just like any code following the `return` statement.

The only thing that "happens" is that your automatic-storage-duration objects (roughly speaking, your local variables) will be automatically destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

The `return` statement, from any deepest if-statement, loop, or switch; will cause program control to *return* to the caller. It may return with a value, for a non-void function, or simply exit from the current function without any *output* for the caller.

Other than function, a `return` statement can be similarly used to exit from a **lambda** (since C++11). Semantics remain the same. Hence, if you see `return` statement inside a lambda (or multilevel nested lambda), they *may not* return from the **function**, but only from given lambda.

In both cases, locally declared variables will go out of scope, their memory (if held by some pointer) will be invalid. The destructors will be called (if allocated on stack).

Comment: What do lambdas have to do with it?

Comment: Why not? OP is asking the meaning of "return" keyword.

Comment: Yes, "in this case".

Answer (score -3):

You have nested for loops. However the function itself returns a constant value of -1. Perhaps you could be clearer in what you are asking